# Removing semi-transparent overlay on flattened image

Tags: image, image-processing, transparency, photoshop, gimp

A solution to this problem seems to not exist but I find it hard to believe it is not possible.

Imagine you have an image with a semi-transparent overlay (color=black, transparency=50%), whether over the whole image or just a portion, doesn't matter. How could one convert the pixels underneath to their original color, in essence removing the black overlay.

Just like a simple algebra equation we should be able to rearrange the variables to solve for the "original pixels" under the overlay. Something along the lines of -

original pixels * semi-transparent overlay = new pixels
original pixels = semi-transparent overlay / new pixels

Obviously such an equation over simplifies the problem but I think that gets my point across. Since we know the color and percent transparency, why couldn't we "retrieve" the colors of the underlying pixels?

EDIT:  Mark Ransom in the comments is correct, if you know the transparency is 50% then simply multiplying by 2 gets you to the original color. Any recommendations on how to apply this to a whole region in Photoshop or GIMP? Certainly doing it pixel by pixel is out of the question.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should explain your exact task a bit, just to make sure you are not overlooking some just-ignore-the-alpha-channel approach. Apart from that, what did you learn from the wiki-article on [alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)

Comment: If your parameters are correct, black overlay at 50%, the solution is trivial: multiply each pixel value by 2. The general case is much more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "divide" layer mode will do what you want. In the case of semi-transparent black, use a gray with the value equal to the opacity value of the overlayed layer.